# Typescript recognizes conditional function parameter as union type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to create a function with conditional parameters. Where, based on the first parameter, the second parameter will be changed. But typescript isn't asserting the correct type automatically inside a conditional block. How can I do that?

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3gWAFBSgOwEMBbCALijmEQEt8BzHAXxx1EigEF8bjCAbVBhx44kAMY0IcClVoNmrbADMArvnHAaAe3xR6EYAB4AKlAgAPYBHwATOFADkqhIkdQAPk8I8+-RwB8ABTE2rYQ-Cbg5FAmADRQoeH8FGaW1nYOzq7uAPywrlAU3LwCAJTCuFA0ylAhYRFRHCgtTi5IjhVYVXhJEQB0RKR4eCJQTOb8CJUjiQ38-WIQktJjLNjrQA)

Here is my code:

```js
type User = {
  name: string
}

type Animal = {
  species: string
}

function get<T extends 'user' | 'animal'>(modelType: T, model: T extends 'user' ? User : Animal) {
  if (modelType === 'user') {
    model.name // Property 'name' does not exist on type 'User | Animal'.     
  } else {
    model.species // Property 'species' does not exist on type 'User | Animal'.
  }
}
```

If check if type is 'user', typescript should recognize that the model is User, according conditional type

Comment: seems overly complex to me. isn't the whole point of typescript to verify variable types at a pre-compiled state?

Comment: This is a missing feature of TypeScript; see [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014); checking `modelType` has no effect on `T`.  If you want behavior like this you'd need to refactor to form the language understands,m like making `modelType`/`model` properties of a destructured discriminated union, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/Wylxxm).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing? (Pls mention @jcalz if you reply so I'm notified)

Comment: Why not just overloading?

Comment: @jcalz I got it now! You’re correct. I resolved it using a type guard then worked.